# How to create a simple partitioned matrix

Tags: matrices

I wish to create a matrix as displayed in the encircled region on the right
(taken from [here](http://wp.kntu.ac.ir/hadizadeh/pdf/latex/lesson_12[1].pdf))
[image]

However, the code on the left does not seem to be generating the vertical through the matrix. Instead I am only getting one horizontal bar through the matrix.

Can someone please provide a simple code that generates the block/partitioned matrix on the right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a vertical bar in the format specification: `c|c`. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
C=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
M & N \\
\hline
R & S
\end{array}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, don't use `$$...$$` in modern LaTeX documents; use `\[...\]`. See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/3954).

Comment: Is there an easy way to use dotted or dashed lines instead of solid with `\hline` and `{c|c}`?